# How do I add the widget that shows my total reputation across sites to my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, combined-flair

I've noticed that a few users have something like this on their profiles:

[image]

It shows their total reputation across all sites.

How can I add that to my profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5775259/fiksdal) then you see a tab at the very right called "flair" (this tab is just visible to you).

There, you will find an image, whose last part is your network user ID code like this:

```
https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5775259.png
#                                    ^^^^^^^
#                                    your network ID
```

Let's check it... and yes, it works!

> [image]

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I will have to wait 10 minutes to accept.

Comment: Did I do it correctly?

Comment: @Fiksdal [yes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OPIzs.png)! If you also want it to appear in your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/5775259/fiksdal), go there and click _Update profile info_.

Comment: @Fiksdal nice :) In case you did not see it, check my updated comment before about the network profile.

Comment: Oh, so I can paste that html code into my profile?

Comment: @Fiksdal you can have this image in the _About me_ section, like [this user](http://stackexchange.com/users/1086299/terdon), for example. Just update your profile info copying it from a site where you have added it.

Comment: Yup, I used to html code, it worked :)